# Configure keyboard codes on the client-side to move PuTTY cursor between words

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, putty, key-binding, escape-characters

Related to StackOverflow [Bash CTRL to move cursor between words/strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings).  While that thread provided good answers on the server-side, I'm looking for ways to control this on the client-side.

I have two Windows 10 PCs from different manufacturers that send different escape codes for `CTRL-<ARROW>`.  They are running the same PuTTY version and configuration.  Both Windows are configured with the same keyboard language.

One sends codes that moves the cursor between words, the other does not.  I understand I can configure the server-side to map the non-conforming codes to move between words.  However, there are just too many servers to make this practical and some are embedded systems that make this impossible.  Instead, I'm looking for a way to tell the client to use the desired key codes.

The keyboard that works on all servers sends:

> ```
> ^[[1;5D = ctrl-left
> ^[[1;5C = ctrl-right
> ```

The other keyboard sends:

> ```
> ^[OD = ctrl-left
> ^[OC = ctrl-right
> ```

None of the servers map `^[OD` nor `^[OC` in their `/etc/inputrc` file (e.g. `bind -p | grep forward-word`)

How do I control the keyboard codes on the client-side?